# Table with database values and user input

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've been wrestling with this issue on and off for quite a while now, and just like driving around lost in a strange city, I am finally breaking down for direction! I am developing table with values from a database, but also need a column that will process user input. I have been able to display the table but my input is not updating the necessary database element. Code below:

```
<?php
include("pogsatbetbuddy.inc.php");        
$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name)
    or die("Did Not Connect");
$query="SELECT * FROM $tbl2_name ORDER BY $tbl2_name.$col_name ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
    or die("Query Not Working");      
echo"<table border='1'
          <form name='payments' action='' method='POST'>
           <tr>
             <td class='update' colspan='5'>
              <button data-theme='b' id='submit' type='submit'>Update</button>
             </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
         <th class='profile'>Last Name</th>
         <th class='profile'>First Name</th>
     <th class='profile'>Saturday Payment Owing</th>
             <th class='profile'>Enter Payment</th>
             <th class='profile'>Saturday Balance</th>                   
    </tr>";
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
   extract ($row);
   echo"<tr>
         <td class='profile'>$lastname</td>
         <td class='profile'>$firstname</td>
         <td class='profile'>$owingsat</td>
             <td class='profile'><input type='number' name='paidsat' value=''/></td>
             <td class='profile'>$owingsat-$paidsat</td>                 
        </tr>";
       }
     echo "</form>";
 echo "</table>";
```

This displays the table in the way I want. Having worked through the results of the following code, it seems that I am returning a null value, so I am thinking I have an issue with either the form action or the submit Update button, but can not find the solution after much experimentation and searching. Balance of code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['paidsat']))
 {
  $paidsat = $_POST['paidsat'];
    if(($paidsat) != null)
     {
       $stmt = $cxn->prepare("UPDATE $tbl2_name SET paidsat = ? WHERE firstname=? and lastname=?");
       $stmt->bind_param('sss', $paidsat, $firstname, $lastname);
       $status = $stmt->execute();       
        if($status === true)  //To check if the execute was successful
        {
         echo("<p class='click'>You have successfully added the payment for $firstname $lastname\n<br /></p>");
        }
      }
   else echo"Not Successful";
  }
 else echo "<p class='click'>Make your changes as required</p>";
 mysqli_close($cxn);
```

Everything comes to a crashing halt at the second if statement.....or should I say, although things look pretty, they don't function! Thanks in advance, appreciate any help!

Comment: where have you assigned  $tbl2_name ?

Comment: Include file....pogsatbetbuddy.inc.php

Comment: I have posted a first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have a proper value  for $tbl2_name checking

```
 var_dump($tbl2_name)
```

in your code before the update

and for debug try using  a string concatenation  like

```
"UPDATE " . $tbl2_name . "  SET paidsat = ? WHERE firstname=? and lastname=?";
```

and try use

```
  if( $paidsat  != NULL )
```

and last check if  you have proper value for update

```
  paidsat = ? WHERE firstname=? and lastname=?
```

Try

```
 var_dump( $paidsat);
 var_dump( $firstname);
 var_dump(  $lastname);
```

and build  a proper select for test if you value math the rows you think and 
test this select in you db console

Comment: Seems OK there. It gets hung up before it reaches the UPDATE statement by the if(($paidsat) != null) statement which I think suggests I am not getting a value when I click Submit. Rest of table populates from the database using $tbl2_name

Comment: I have update the answer  .. remove the () around $paidsat and use NULL

Comment: Tried it, no luck.

Comment: Try using  NULL (uppercase) and let me know

Comment: Is it possible that it is my Form Action?

Comment: No luck with the uppercase

Comment: Well in these case .. try commenting selectively  the code .. eg: the code inside the if( $paidsat  != NULL ) {..... } until the related closing } . for find the code that create the error .. and please you can show me the error message

Comment: Don't get an error message, just no update to the database from the input. Thanks for working with me on this

Comment: Then the problem is related to your data  .. check for data in where condition and data in you db .. . i have update the answer

Comment: The var_dump helped, thanks. While I am just trying to update one record, it seems I am running through the entire list. Output was 'string(1) "0" string(3) "Ben" string(6) "WILSON"' which is not the record I was trying to update

Comment: Well if my answer is right and lead you to the solution of yur problem  please mark my answer as accepted ..

Comment: Definitely pointed me in the right direction, thanks. I am not quite there yet, but I now know that I am only updating the last record in the list, not the specific one I am trying to update. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on why that is happening and how to correct it. Thanks again

Comment: You must thinking at your where condition .. could be you submit (and send in by $_POST) the   last value of firtsname and lastname

Comment: Yes, I took the input out of the where loop, and only have the option of changing the last value...any thoughts on how to fix? Thanks

Comment: If you have an id for the row you want update you should add the hidden input (so  is not visible) with this id  .. this input is submited  togheter with your other input and  so you can use this value for update the row  you need ..Hope is clear otherwise post  a new proper question  for this